# Is this that-clause a complement?

Tags: complements

> In that discomfort, breathing quicklime and tar, no one could see very
>   well how from the bowels of the earth there was rising not only the
>   largest house in the town, but the most hospitable and cool house **that**
>   had ever existed in the region of the swamp. 
> (One Hundred Years of
>   Solitude, tr. by Gregory Rabassa)

The that-clause is a complement providing the criterion for ‘the largest’ and ‘the most’, isn’t it? (It seems like the ‘indirect complement’ that is said in ‘The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language.')

Comment: ***I really do not understand what you are asking.*** Simplify your sentence: *“No one could see that there was rising not only X but also Y.”* And then go from there. X and Y are the two things that are rising.  The *that* is describing the [largest **and** the most hospital **and** the most cool (=coolest)] house ***which*** had every existed. It seems quite simple when you boil it down like that, and I cannot see where you are confused or what you are confused about. What are you really asking here? Try rewriting that passage into several short sentences for clarity.

Comment: @tchrist: Seems pretty clear to me. OP is asking what the final "that-clause" refers to. He's not asking whether *that* could be replaced by *which*. But it *is* complicated by the fact that the passage says *cool* because it's elided from ***most** cool.* That's a "hypothetical" second element qualified by the final clause, because it wouldn't make sense to refer to *the **cool** house that had ever existed*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the *that-clause* has no grammatical relationship with *the largest*. It's quite possible there was previously a larger house in the town (that's just been demolished, perhaps).

What the final clause modifies is specifically the word ***most***, but it's complicated by the fact that strictly speaking there's a deleted second instance *(the **most** hospitable and [the **most**] cool house)*. They're *both* being modified, even though one isn't actually there any more.

It's perfectly possible to describe something with just a superlative. For example,...

[*She was the sweetest girl.*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22up%20she%20was%20the%20sweetest%20girl%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22she%20was%20the%20sweetest%20girl%20now%22&oq=%22she%20was%20the%20sweetest%20girl%20now%22&gs_l=serp.3...12541.13501.1.13914.4.4.0.0.0.0.59.193.4.4.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..7.0.0.DEafwBCv8Sw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.50165853,d.d2k,pv.xjs.s.en_US.seW1cfrvSKg.O&fp=c74fb9c2dbf5756c&biw=1369&bih=911)

...which can be modified it with a "that-clause"...

[*She was the sweetest girl **that I had ever known.***](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=tFrKp5UpewMC&pg=PA55&dq=%22she%20was%20the%20sweetest%20girl%20that%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=fnH8UdGrHa6N0wWVz4H4BQ&sqi=2&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22she%20was%20the%20sweetest%20girl%20that%22&f=false)

That's all that's happening in OP's example. Without the qualification, the default meaning would be *the most hospitable [and coolest] house **ever, anywhere***.

Comment: It's not just **any** _that_-clause. It's a restrictive relative clause (one can substitute _which_, but not leave it out, because it's the subject -- this is criterial for relative clauses), and it's part of the superlative construction, so it **does** have a grammatical relationship with _the largest_, since it identifies the comparison field of the superlative. Oh, and the answer to the question is: "No, this _that_-clause is not a complement clause; it's a **relative** clause."

Comment: @John: I don't quite follow that. Are you saying the final *restrictive relative clause* directly relates to/qualifies *the largest*? I can't see that. It seems to me *the largest* and *the most hospitable and cool* are only interelated by virtue of the fact that they both refer to the same ***house***. But per my answer, it might not be the largest house that's *ever* been there - I just read it as saying it's the largest house there ***right now***.

Comment: No, I'm saying that the Superlative construction requires some constituent that defines the comparison space. There has to be something, and there are several alternatives: _the tallest man in the world_ uses a preposition phrase; _the tallest man (that) I've ever seen_ uses a relative clause. This is the relative clause. Note: relative clauses are not complement clauses; relative clauses are adjective clauses while complement coffees are noun clauses. Quite different constructions. So calling something a _that_-clause doesn't identify it.

Comment: @John: That's cleared up a *lot* for me! I avoided echoing OP's *complement* because I didn't really understand what it meant in this context (plus I failed miserably to find any useful online definition of an *indirect complement*). But I can understand "relative clauses are adjective clauses". And armed with better ways of describing things, I now feel reasonably confident in saying that unless there's an explicit *relative / adjective (/qualifying?)* clause, the "default comparison space" for *She was the prettiest girl* is in fact *ever, anywhere*.

Comment: Try [this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/aue/complmnt.html) and [this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf) and [this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf). There's an early chapter in McCawley on complements, because they're so important in English.

Comment: @John: I was pretty sure when I put up my *sweetest girl* example that it was effectively the same as OP's. But I see from your first link that *this **that** complementizer is optional unless it introduces a sentence* (I assume this is still "the same" that! :). And although I'm happy to omit *that* in my example, I can't seem to do the same with OP's. Is that because they're *fundamentally* different in some way that I can't see, or is it just a minor quirk of the verb forms involved, idiomatic usage, or whatever?

Comment: That's a peculiarity of the sentence. Relative pronouns can only be omitted when they're not the subject. If they're the subject, they gotta stay, because of Rule One.